# How to pull out strings from array on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, string, substring

I want to pull out a string from an array by index.

e.g array with object: @"Hello", @"World"

How to get @"World" from it? I use array[1], but it seems not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find [this method](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex:) works well:

```
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an enumerator, like this:

```
NSEnumerator* enumerator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
ArrayObject* myObject;

while (myObject = [enumerator nextObject]) 
    {
// do something with myObject
}
```